# Printing a word from file, which contain that many characters as we declare

Tags: bash, grep, command-line-arguments

I want to print a word from file, which contain that many characters that I declare as first argument in command line. Is there any possibility to use egrep and replace e.g. {3} with first argument from command line ?

```
egrep -x -w '^.{3}$' inputfile.txt
```

I mean something like that, but it doesn't work

```
egrep -x -w '^.{$1}$' inputfile.txt
```

Comment: Probably, you mean `grep -oE '^[[:alnum:]]{3}\b' inputfile.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work:

```
egrep -x -w '^.{'$1'}$' inputfile.txt
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer